# invalid ELF header in node.js on linux putty

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux

I am facing the error invalid ELF header when I'm trying to run my node.js project on my printer having linux os using putty. The project was developed on windows. I'm attaching the whole error that I'm receiving. Please help.

```
stack=[Error: /sirius/rw/test/node-v8.11.1-linux-armv7l/node_modules/ref/build/Release/binding.node: invalid ELF header,     
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:681:18),     
at Module.load (module.js:565:32),     
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12),     
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3),     
at Module.require (module.js:596:17),     
at require (internal/module.js:11:18),     
at bindings (/sirius/rw/test/node-v8.11.1-linux-armv7l/node_modules/ref/node_modules/bindings/bindings.js:81:44),     
at Object.<anonymous> (/sirius/rw/test/node-v8.11.1-linux-armv7l/node_modules/ref/lib/ref.js:5:47),     
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30),     
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)]
```

Comment: Did you run `npm install` first?

Comment: yes. still the same error

Comment: My guess is that some file needs to be rebuilt for the current architecture. You could try deleting the entire node_modules folder before running `npm install` again? This question seems to be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42022702/npm-ref-could-not-locate-the-bindings-file-error

Answer (score 2):

Because the project was developed on windows; npm needs to compile some node modules specially for the linux OS, so simply using the modules as is won’t always work.

First remove the node modules:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Then generate the same modules for linux using the following command:

```
npm update
```

I hope this helps